# Couldn't update from url

Tags: php, sql

I have this part of code. But when I click to https://..../posts.php?unpublish=4 nothing happens. The page just refreshing and no logs. When I click it should change value from 1 to 0. My code is working on XAMPP, but not working in GoGaddy Shared hosting..

```
// if I clicks the publish post button

if (isset($_GET['publish']) || isset($_GET['unpublish'])) {
$message = "";
if (isset($_GET['publish'])) {
    $message = "Post published successfully";
    $post_id = $_GET['publish'];
} else if (isset($_GET['unpublish'])) {
    $message = "Post successfully unpublished";
    $post_id = $_GET['unpublish'];
}

togglePublishPost($post_id, $message);

}

function togglePublishPost($post_id, $message)
{
global $conn;
$sql = "UPDATE posts SET published=!published WHERE id=$post_id";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    $_SESSION['message'] = $message;
    header("location: posts.php");
    exit(0);
}
}
```

Comment: `SET published=!unpublish` I think the problem is here

Comment: sorry, but I have same error with SET published=!published also

Comment: I think it is not a php Problem, it is a SQL Problem. Try this: `UPDATE posts SET published = NOT published WHERE id = $post_id`

Comment: @Spirit thank you dude, it works!!! I have created new question. Can you please help me with that one also? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55712048

Comment: @grb I have posted my comment as answer, that other people can find the solution easily. I hope you accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is not in the PHP-Code, it is in the SQL-Query.

To use the opposite value of `published` you have to use `NOT`.
Use this query:

```
$sql = "UPDATE posts SET published = NOT published WHERE id = $post_id";
```